# Correct way to return a single result where multiple results may exist

Tags: java

In the following code, the `ssNo` parameter should ensure that only a single `Employee` satisfies the query condition:

```
Employee employee = null;
List<Employee> results = (List<Employee>) query.execute(ssNo);
if (results.iterator().hasNext())
{
    for (Employee r : results)
    {
        employee = r;
    }
}
return employee;
```

But if there are multiple results, the `for` loop ensures that the last `Employee` in the loop will be returned:

```
for (Employee r : results)
{
    employee = r;
}
```

Is there a cleaner way to perform this kind of check?

Comment: So the `ssNo` parameter doesn't ensure that only 1 `Employee` satisfies the query condition and this is why you need the loop ?

Comment: Wouldn't the "correct way" of handling that situation depend on what the requirements are?

Answer (score 8):

Following the mantra that "less code is good", this code is equivalent to your code, but expressed in much less code and more clearly.

```
List<Employee> results = (List<Employee>) query.execute(ssNo);
return results.isEmpty() ? null : results.get(results.size() - 1);
```

It's more common to see the first element returned:

```
return results.isEmpty() ? null : results.get(0);
```

Another common pattern is:

```
if (results.size() > 1) 
    throw new IllegalStateException("Multiple results found, but at most one was expected");
```

Note that you can over-abbreviate your code to the point of "encryption", but as long as the code is still clear, less code is always better than more code.

Answer (score 5):

Choosing the last employee is not a good idea, because if you expect to get only one employee, but instead, you get several ones, then you are likely to have a bug in your application or some data integrity problem that will go unnoticed, because you just return an arbitrary one. I'd throw an exception instead.

A clean API would look something like this:

```
// This returns a list of employees matching your search criteria
// Typical criteria are names, age, salary ranges, etc
// It will never be null, but maybe an empty list
List<Employee> getEmployeesByCriteria(... criteria);

// This will return at most one employee, depending on your search criteria
// Typically, you'll use an ID as criteria. If you don't find the employee
// you can either return null, or throw an exception. If you find several
// employees, then you should always throw an exception.
Employee getEmployeeByCriteria(... criteria) throws SomeException;
```

Comment: +1 - it sounds like an exceptional condition where the integrity of the data has been compromised.

Comment: @coobird. You're probably right. But maybe it's just an attempt for defensive programming

Answer (score 0):

A minor simplification could be to remove the `if` check since the loop will get the last result anyway if the results are more than one.

If the result is only one that the first one is the last one so the `if` check is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree with Lukas Eder. If you're using a database, you should make sure the ssNo field is unique. If you are working only in memory, you should use a Hashtable using the ssNo as a key, and that would throw an exception when you try to insert on a key already used.

In any case, this part of your code is not the place (or this should not be) to check the validity of your datas.

Answer (score 0):

If the query return more the one expected results you should throw an exception that this is not correct.

But if you are 100% sure that this is good way for your case then this look better.

```
  List<Employee> results = (List<Employee>) query.execute(ssNo);

  if(results.size() > 0) {
    return results.get(results.size() - 1);
  }
```